# According to Catholicism, did Jesus have a Guardian Angel?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus, angels, guardian-angels

According to Catholicism, did Jesus have a Guardian Angel?

If so do we know their name(s)?

We see the Angels ministering to the needs of the Godman while on earth, but Scripture does not employ the term Guardian Angel to them.

> Then Jesus saith to him: Begone, Satan: for it is written, The Lord thy God shalt thou adore, and him only shalt thou serve.
> 11 Then the devil left him; and behold angels came and ministered to him. - [Matthew 4:10-11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%204&version=DRA)

According to Catholic theologians or mystics, who was Our Lord’s guardian angel(s), if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We see not one but many angels, administering to Jesus , for instance after the temptations in the wilderness:

> Then the devil left him, and suddenly angels came and waited on him. - (Mtt 4: 11)

But we see only one angel giving comapany to him at the Garden of Gethsemane:

> He withdrew about a stone’s throw beyond them, knelt down and prayed,  “Father, if you are willing, take this cup from me; yet not my will, but yours be done.”  An angel from heaven appeared to him and strengthened him. - (Lk  22: 41-43).

This angel is named as Chamuel in the traditions. "This angel performed a vital ministry for Christ just prior to His going to the cross to die for the sins of humankind," writes Ron Rhodes in his book Angels Among Us: Separating Fact from Fiction. (Courtesy: Learn Religions.com)

We also see that Jesus was in a position to seek physical protection by the angels, when he was being arrested and taken away by the soldiers:

> With that, one of Jesus’ companions reached for his sword, drew it out and struck the servant of the high priest, cutting off his ear. “Put your sword back in its place,” Jesus said to him, “for all who draw the sword will die by the sword.  Do you think I cannot call on my Father, and he will at once put at my disposal more than twelve legions of angels? - (Mat 26:51-53).

So, the scriptures  do not as such say that Jesus had a Guardian Angel attached to him, but being Son of God, he had the services of many angels  at “short notice”.

PS: I am not aware if any Catholic Theologian or Mystic has made an authentic statement on the subject.

Comment: Please confirm that the Church still uses the word “Godman” for Jesus.  In non-Christian countries like India, the term has a rather sinister use to mean one who proclaims himself to be the incarnation of one of the many gods , and has a significant number of followers .

Comment: Simply read any of Dom Gueranger’s works on **The Liturgical Year**!

Comment: Note that according to the 2002 [Directory on Popular Piety](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/ccdds/documents/rc_con_ccdds_doc_20020513_vers-direttorio_en.html#Chapter%20Six), "The practice of assigning names to the Holy Angels should be discouraged, except in the cases of Gabriel, Raphael and Michael whose names are contained in Holy Scripture." So a modern witness to an explicit identification of these angels is unlikely.